# Windows 10 search within images

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, jpeg

Just like Windows 10 will search file content like pdfs etc. is there a way to get it to OCR and search within images?

Especially I have a lot of screenshots etc in a folder of websites or other text and they are stored as jpeg files. Is there a way to get windows to search those?

Alternatively, any other tools or plugins that would accomplish this on Windows or could add metadata to the images so that the native windows indexer could still search them out?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions I see is if you parse the image on making the screenshot, saving the results on local database or in a text file next to the image with the same name. That way you could query your screenshots for text

Comment: Thanks! Good idea. Maybe I can use a script triggered by screenshot captor that I use to get the screenshots in the first place. Would it be possible to save the text as jpeg metadata do you know?

Comment: @curious_cat I'm no expert of this, but a quick google search tells me that you can write custom properties to the EXIF, 64KB limit but should be enough. You can use https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract to extract the text.

Comment: @curious_cat or you can create a small local database, like MongoDB and pair the images up with the text

Answer (score 0):

Search within Windows files is provided by Windows' "Text" Search indexing. Some file formats such as PDF, Docx, etc., are encoded and need a Windows specific search plug-in called an **"iFilter"**, which parses the files for their text contents to allow indexing to store those keywords for fast plain text retrieval.

- For PDF, there are several variants such as the one supplied by Acrobat. There is also a good one from Apryse [PDFlib](https://www.pdflib.com/products/tet-pdf-ifilter/overview) (free for private use)
- For DocX, etc., they are installed by Office

There are no natural iFilter for pixels, unless Microsoft provides one.

- The best solution if you have a PDF filter is to scan to searchable PDF (can be done via tesseract or any OCR related image software), then the searchable contents of the PDF will after a while be added to the "File System Text Search" index.
- Searching speed is hampered by too much data, so compartmentalise the folders you wish to search to reduce the files needing slow searching

  - For example, keep all utility bills in one folder, then you can search just that area for "paid" or "overdue"

Comment: Please use correct markdown, such as for weblinks - please see the formatting bar or the `?` button to the far right on the formatting bar

Comment: Don't worry about the grammar, only the correct markdown for things like weblinks, monospaced code, code boxes, etc. =]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are built in solutions, but I recently stumbled on the [Search for text in pictures](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/search-for-text-in-pictures/9NJNV7SH2413) app, but haven't had the time to try it yet.

Description:

> The App has an OCR- filter that can pull text from any image and search for text in images on the local devices. This allows you to search for words and bring up all results as image where that phrase appears.  It runs only on the local device and protects your privacy.
>
> Very useful to find  documents, invoices, Wi-Fi passwords  and anything else that you’ve saved by taking a picture.

Comment: Please use correct markdown, such as for weblinks - please see the formatting bar or the `?` button to the far right on the formatting bar

Comment: @JW0914 I'll never take advise from someone who downvotes my answers for no good reason. https://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mdjxtxhZrU1r9wybv.gif